# Configure Json.net to URL encode certain field

Tags: c#, json.net

Say I have a model class like this:

```
public class MyModelClass
{
    [JsonProperty("first_field"]
    public string FirstField { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("second_field"]
    public string SecondField { get; set; }

    public MyModelClass(string first, string second)
    {
        FirstField = first;
        SecondField = second;
    }
}
```

and let's say I have an instance of this type:

```
var myObject = new MyModelClass("blablabla", "<>@%#^^@!%");
```

When I convert this object into a Json string using Json.net, I get something like:

```
{ 'first_field': 'blablabla', 'second_field': '<>@%#^^@!%' }
```

Is there a way to configure Json.net so that the content of 'SecondField' is URL encoded? Do I need to write my own custom converter or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Can't you use attributes to make the "real" property invisible to the serializer and have an alternate one only used for serialization?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's just one field in one class, you could simply add a read-only property to your class to handle the encoding, and annotate it such that it will take the place of the original property during serialization:

```
    public class MyModelClass
    {
        ...

        [JsonIgnore]
        public string SecondField { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("second_field")]
        private string UrlEncodedSecondField
        {
            get { return System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(SecondField); }
        }

        ...
    }
```

Demo fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MkVBVH

---

If you need this for multiple fields across multiple classes, you could use a solution similar to the one in [Selectively escape HTML in strings during deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32562381/10263), with a couple of minor changes:

1. Create a custom `UrlEncode` attribute and have the resolver look for properties with that attribute rather than the absence of an `AllowHtml` attribute.
2. Change the `HtmlEncodingValueProvider` to a `UrlEncodingValueProvider` and have it apply the encoding in `GetValue` rather than `SetValue` (so that it does the encoding on serialization rather than deserialization).

Here is what the resulting code would look like:

```
public class UrlEncodeAttribute : Attribute { }

public class CustomResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        IList<JsonProperty> props = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);

        // Find all string properties that have a [UrlEncode] attribute applied
        // and attach an UrlEncodingValueProvider instance to them
        foreach (JsonProperty prop in props.Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string)))
        {
            PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty(prop.UnderlyingName);
            if (pi != null && pi.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(UrlEncodeAttribute), true) != null)
            {
                prop.ValueProvider = new UrlEncodingValueProvider(pi);
            }
        }

        return props;
    }

    protected class UrlEncodingValueProvider : IValueProvider
    {
        PropertyInfo targetProperty;

        public UrlEncodingValueProvider(PropertyInfo targetProperty)
        {
            this.targetProperty = targetProperty;
        }

        // SetValue gets called by Json.Net during deserialization.
        // The value parameter has the original value read from the JSON;
        // target is the object on which to set the value.
        public void SetValue(object target, object value)
        {
            targetProperty.SetValue(target, (string)value);
        }

        // GetValue is called by Json.Net during serialization.
        // The target parameter has the object from which to read the string;
        // the return value is the string that gets written to the JSON
        public object GetValue(object target)
        {
            string value = (string)targetProperty.GetValue(target);
            return System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value);
        }
    }
}
```

To use the custom resolver, first decorate any properties that you want to be URL encoded with the new `[UrlEncode]` attribute:

```
public class MyModelClass
{
    [JsonProperty("first_field")]
    public string FirstField { get; set; }

    [UrlEncode]
    [JsonProperty("second_field")]
    public string SecondField { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Then, serialize your model like this:

```
var myObject = new MyModelClass("blablabla", "<>@%#^^@!%");

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CustomResolver(),
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject, settings);
```

Demo fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/iOOzFr

Comment: This looks like an excellent solution but seems incredible that we need 3 classes to achieve this seemingly simple goal.

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by @brian-rogers is excellent, but I wanted to present an alternative that, I believe, is simpler:

```
public class UrlEncodingConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value == null) return;
        var encodedValue = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode((string)value);
        writer.WriteValue(encodedValue);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.Value == null) return null;
        var decodedValue = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(reader.Value.ToString());
        return decodedValue;
    }
}
```

which can be used like so:

```
public class MyModelClass
{
    [JsonProperty("first_field")]
    public string FirstField { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("second_field")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(UrlEncodingConverter))]
    public string SecondField { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var myObject = new MyModelClass("blablabla", WebUtility.UrlEncode("<>@%#^^@!%"));
```

You need to add `System.Net` to your Using-directives

Comment: Unfortunately, I need "myObject" to contain the un-encoded value. I only need the value to be encode when converted to Json

Comment: then either use `WebUtility.UrlDecode` whenever you need it or use the UrlEncode method only when you call the function to convert it into JSON